# What are the main approaches to the foundation of statistics without probability

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, references, philosophical

The frequentist, likelihood and, to an even greater extent, Bayesian approaches to statistics are all based on probability. Without probability, it seems difficult to use a data sample ("seen" cases), to infer results about a more general population ("unseen" cases), and estimate the uncertainty inherent in such a process. Thus it would appear that all we can do is descriptive statistics, as well as some trivial inequalities (such as, if we observe a person of height 2.0 mt, we know that the maximum height in the population of all living persons is $\geq$ 2.0 mt).

Or is it? Are there mathematically rigorous approaches to the foundation of statistics, which do not rely on the theory of probability, and can you point me to references on the subject?

Comment: The main appproaches? I wonder if there is a single approach. Curious to learn more.

Comment: For small datasets with few variables, numerical and graphical descriptive summaries can be very useful. For huge datasets with many variables, some algorithmic methods that may rely more on computer power than probability theory are showing promise. But why would anyone want to pursue either path without insights gained from probability theory?

Comment: @BruceET there is at least the duality diagram approach: http://statweb.stanford.edu/~susan/talks/foundations.pdf of which I know very little (basically nothing).As  to the "why", I have absolutely no idea.

Comment: @RichardHardy see my reply to BruceET for one approach (but don't ask me anything about it).

Comment: I would point out that Cox's method follows from Aristotelian logic.  It doesn't define probability.  De Finetti's method is doesn't use the word probability.  He instead speaks in terms of bets.  Probability follows from it and therefore statistics, but it is grounded in gambling.  Savage's is grounded in preference theory.  Likewise, Kolmogorov's method follows from measurement and not probability.  It is a consequence.  De Finetti argued that probability, like utility, was a mental construction and did not exist except to help think about things.

Comment: Statistics get grounded in probability because it creates a useful interim construction that is of interest in its own right, but there is no reason one is obligated to formalize the idea of probability before formalizing a statistic.  It would just make it very difficult to discuss anything useful about the statistic.  Still, when one considers Frequentist decision theory as a behavioral system of decisions, one could ground a statistic in behavior and pretend the inference was inconsequential.

Comment: I doubt that a seemingly philosophical question is placed correctly at CV. There is a mathematical approach to all of this, and from a mathematical point of view why would you want to look at a different way that is guaranteed to be equivalent? In the end all you need are a bunch of axioms and then take them to the edge. Probability/Stochastics/Statistics are eventually the same subject. The only difference is the point of view, or rather the direction it takes.